# Can't set default node version in NVM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04, nvm

I can't set the default version in NVM. I always get this warning: *Version xx.xx.x does not exist.* no matter what I type. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and have ZSH installed with the script. This is what I get when I do *nvm list* :

```
->       system
default -> 10.15.3 (-> N/A)
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/ -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.15.3 (-> N/A)
```

Comment: install a node version using nvm.. then "nvm list" and u should see , among the stdout , a version that u can switch to.. until u have done install of node using nvm u dont have any entity to control with nvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first install your node version.

Supposing it's the latest stable version (in March 2022 is 16.14.0) you should do

```
nvm install 16.14.0
```

Then, check if version was successfully installed with

```
nvm list
```

And finally, set the default version with

```
nvm alias default 16.14.0
```

Now you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install a node version that will be set as your default version. Use `nvm list` to get the full list of available versions and use `nvm install` to install it. Use `nvm install node` for the latest version.